# Remove unused source code files using eclipse/ Flash builder 4.6

Tags: eclipse, flash-builder, project, flash-builder4.5

i have a project having lots of file, around 4500 file in all Project. i separated it in 40 library project.Now my problem is that it taking too much time to Compile. so i increase a memory of Flash builder. This gives me little improvement to compile. i am sure that i have too much file which is not used in my project. so now i want to remove it by plug of Flash Builder / Eclipse. Because it is too much headache process to see that "xyz.as/mxml" file is used in any other file or if it is used in Other file say "abx.as/mxml" then again i have a question that "abx.as/mxml" is useful file or used in any other file. so you have any idea or hint please give me. Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1):

One thing you can try is to use the `size-report` of your flex compilation : [flex compiler options](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf67110-7ff4.html)
This way you will have an idea of which classes are really used in your libraries and therefore wich ones aren't because the flex compiler only link to classes you really need in your compiled swf. 
This not ideal but it can avoid a lot of manual process pain.

Comment: Thanks for reply. let me try!!

Answer (score 1):

Add this param to your compiler:

```
-link-report output.xml
```

this information will help you.

Comment: not getting anything in output.xml, i'll be wrong in terms of use this command. so i describe it how i use this

Comment: 1. change compiler setting from flex Compiler in project property and add Additional argument in it as you give
2. output.xml file created in project
3. run the project again
4. but no effect retrieved, seen build properly and seen run properly, no output generated in outout.xml, run just like normal

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it would work for flash-builder, but for Java there is the [UCDetector](http://www.ucdetector.org).

Comment: Installed Success fully. but not worked after restart. so clean and build my project again then try to remove the unused source code. but it not responding.........